# Simple python GET request throws error msg when I try with a particular path

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to activate a Flask server by sending a URL with data in the path. The path contains an API key and access token so I can't paste the exact contents of the string but I can delete some of it and post that.

The code itself is very simple:

```
import requests

url2 = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/ready/"  # this is the correct IP and port #
path = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/myUsername/"

x = requests.get(url2)
# x = requests.get(url2 + path)

print(x.status_code)
```

doing `.get()` on simply "url2" returns a **404** from my flask server, proving that I have the right base URL. That's fine and expected, as the route I am trying to match is this:

`@app.route("/ready/<consumer_token>/<consumer_secret>/<access_token>/<access_secret>/<username>/", methods=["GET"])`

Then when I do `.get()` on the `url + path` combo gives me this:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`

I tried restarting my PC (no effect) and disabling my firewall (also no effect). One StackOverflow thread suggested adding headers, which I did -- also no effect.

Also tried:

```
s = requests.Session()

s.get(url2 + path)
```

Same error.

No clue guys... thanks everyone who reads or responds

Comment: Probably the path is not a valid url. I would suggest sending all these data like "consumer token" or "secret" as a POST and not in url if you want it to be really "secret"

Comment: Your're going to need to show the code in handler. That's likely where the issue is.